# An example of a topological space $(X,T)$ and a non-injective function $f : X \to Y $ s. t. $Tf$ is a topology and an example where $Tf$ isn't.

Tags: general-topology

I appreciate that for an injective function $f(A\cap B) = f(A)\cap f(B)$ and that's why, if the function is injective, then the range of a topological space is also a topological space.  I'm supposing that, since it's not necessarily the case that $f(A\cap B) = f(A)\cap f(B)$ if the function is not injective, then there are some functions where the range is not a topology.  I just cannot figure any out.  In particular, can anyone think of examples in  the standard topology on $\Bbb R$ ?

Comment: My edit was for a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, for you, $\mathscr{T}_{f} = \lbrace f(A)\subseteq f(X)\mid A\in\mathscr{T}_{X}\rbrace$

Now, if you have $f:X\rightarrow Y$ continue and surjective, you can define the Quotient Topology on Y, and this Topology depends on $f$ that not have to be injective.

For the second example, you can take spaces like $\mathbb{R}$ that have a countable base $\mathscr{B}=\lbrace B_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\rbrace$, and think of a map $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(B_{n})=\frac{1}{n}$.

It is clear that

$$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} f(B_{n})=[0, \frac{1}{n}]$$
So $\mathscr{T}_{f}$ can't be a Topology because the arbitrary union of elements in $\mathscr{T}_{f}$ isn't an element of $\mathscr{T}_{f}$.

Comment: is {1,1/2,1/3,1/4,...} = to {0, 1/n} ?